# Fresh Ubuntu 19.04 installation only booting in recovery mode. (failed to reset PPM!)

Tags: boot, nvidia

I just did a fresh Ubuntu 19.04 install alongside Windows 10 from USB.
Now, that installation won't boot to the login screen. The installation starts to hang after the following messages:

```
ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!
ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM init failed (-110)
```

Windows 10 still works fine, so GRUB ain't the problem.

My specs are the following:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- RAM: 16 GB DDR4 @ 3200Mhz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
- Mainboard: ASUS PRIME B450M-A

I also tried to run `nvidia-detector` in recovery mode and that returned nothing.

I installed an ssh-server via recovery mode so I can ssh into the machine.

Did anyone encounter this problem, too? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97546/discussion-on-question-by-tram98-fresh-ubuntu-19-04-installation-only-booting-in).

Comment: I could not solve the problem on my machine. I just installed Debian 10 instead which worked fine for me.